# how to connect MYSQL server using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, connection

I want to use MYSQL server with my asp.net application. But i am not able to connect to it. I am getting error that is "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified " .

My code is:-

```
 System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection cn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=new_testdb; User=root;Password=abc123#;");
    cn.Open();

    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand cmd = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand();

    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter adp = null;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    cmd.Connection = cn;

    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from new_table";

    adp = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);

    adp.Fill(ds, "new_table");

    this.GridView1.DataSource = ds;

    this.GridView1.DataMember = "new_table";

    cn.Close();
```

Comment: Did you install the MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver?

Comment: i don't know i have installed only MYSQL server.. is it some different than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download ADO.NET MySql [Connector API](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) (managed MySql Data provider) instead of [ODBC](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) Driver.

EDIT: [Connector/NET Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples.html)

Comment: @raman - Then don't use Odbc. Add the reference of MySql.Data.Dll in your project and use classes from MySql.Data.MySqlClient namespace.

Comment: can you provide me any link that will helpful to me because i am new to MYSQL. I didn't try this server with asp.net so.

Answer (score 1):

You also may connect to MySQL with [dotConnect for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/) components.

Try to build the connection string with [MySqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please see here [My SQL ConnectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) or [ConnectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Left btn on database in server explorer, select properties copy connection string;

2.`string c= persistsecurityinfo=True;server=localhost;user id=root;password=admin;database=sam;`

1. ```
           MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(c);

           cn.Open();
           Response.Write("Connection successful !!");
           MySqlDataAdapter Mda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from tblName", cn);
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           Mda.Fill(ds, "tblName");
           GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["tblName"];
           GridView1.DataBind();
   ```
2. Make sure that :-

   `using System.Data;`

   `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`

imported...  :)